# Join/slice adjunction and lifting problems

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

Let $C \in sSet$ be a quasicategory. $*$ denote the join of simplicial sets. Then consider $- * X \colon sSet \to sSet_{X/}$, where $sSet_{X/}$ is the slice category of simplicial set under $X$, with objects $X \to Y$.

For $p \colon X \to Y$, $X_{/p}$ is $p$ evaluated at right adjoint of $- * X$.

$C_{/x}$ is $x \colon \triangle^0 \to C$ evaluated at  right adjoint of $-*\triangle^0$.

I'm trying to make sense of the bijective correspondence as shown below.

[image]

I get that $\triangle^n \to C_{/x}$ correspond to $\triangle^n * \triangle^0 \to C$, but I have no idea how other maps correspond.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is adapted from Chapter 3 of "The Theory of Quasicategories and Its Applications Vol. 2" by Andre Joyal. Warning: The notation is different.)

### Notation and Background

Fix a simplicial set $T \in \textsf{sSet}$. Let $T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}$ denote the category whose objects are simplicial maps $T \to X$ and whose morphisms are commuting triangles.

We have a functor
$$ \left(-\right) \ast T \colon \textsf{sSet} \to T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}$$ that maps a simplicial set $X$ to the object $T = \emptyset \ast T \to X \ast T$ in the slice category. This functor admits a right adjoint
$$ T \downarrow \left(-\right) \colon T \downarrow \textsf{sSet} \to \textsf{sSet}$$

Given an object $t \colon T \to X$ in $T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}$, the $n$-simplices of $T \downarrow t$ are given by:
$$ \left(T \downarrow t\right)_{n} = \textsf{sSet}\left(\Delta^{n},T \downarrow t\right) = \left(T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}\right)\left(T \to \Delta^{n} \ast T, t \colon T \to X\right)$$. When the context is clear, we will denote objects $t \colon T \to X$ in the slice category $T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}$ by their codomain $X$. For instance, we write $T \downarrow X$ instead of $T \downarrow t$.

Now, consider a simplicial map $S \xrightarrow{j} T$. We have an induced natural transformation
$$j \downarrow \left(-\right) \colon T \downarrow \left(-\right) \to S \downarrow \left(-\right) $$
On an object $t \colon T \to X$ in $T \downarrow \textsf{sSet}$, this is given on $n$-simplices by:
$$
   \left(j \downarrow X\right)_{n} \colon \left(T \downarrow X\right)_{n} \to \left(S \downarrow X\right)_{n} $$
$$
 \left(\Delta^{n} \ast T \xrightarrow{x} X\right) \mapsto \left( \Delta^{n} \ast S \xrightarrow{\Delta^{n} \ast j} \Delta^{n} \ast T \xrightarrow{x} X\right)
$$

Given simplicial maps $S \xrightarrow{j} T \xrightarrow{t} X \xrightarrow{f} Y$, the naturality square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    T \downarrow X @>j \downarrow X>> S \downarrow X \\
    @V T \downarrow f VV @VV S \downarrow f V \\
    T\downarrow Y @>>j \downarrow j> S \downarrow Y
\end{CD}
induces the pulbback slice $j \vartriangleright f \colon T \downarrow X \to \left(T \downarrow Y\right) \times_{S \downarrow Y} \left(S \downarrow X\right)$

### Lemma

Given simplicial maps $i \colon A \to B$, $j \colon S \to T$, $t \colon T \to X$, and $f \colon X \to Y$, we have a 1-1 correspondence of lifting problems:
$\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD}
    \left(A \ast T\right) \cup_{A \ast S} \left(B \ast S\right) @> >> X \\
    @V i \hat{\ast} j VV @VV f V \\
    B \ast T @>> > Y
\end{CD}
\longleftrightarrow
\begin{CD}
    A @> >> T \downarrow X \\
    @V i VV @VV j \vartriangleright f V \\
    B @>> > \left(T \downarrow Y\right) \times_{S \downarrow Y} \left(S \downarrow X\right)
\end{CD}
$$
Moreover, there is a 1-1 correspondence between their solutions. In particular,
$$\left(i \hat{\ast} j\right) \pitchfork f \Leftrightarrow i \pitchfork \left(j \vartriangleright f\right)$$.

(The correspondence is given by repeatedly using the adjunction between join and slice. This is Lemma 3.14 in Joyal's "The Theory of Quasicategories and Its Applications Vol. 2".)

### Answer to your question

$C_{/x}$ in your question corresponds to $\Delta^{0} \downarrow C$ in my notation. That is, the functor $\Delta^{0} \downarrow \left(-\right)$ applied to the object $x \colon \Delta^{0} \to C$.

Now, in the above lemma, take $i \colon A \to B$ to be the horn inclusion $v^{n}_{j} \colon \Lambda^{n}_{j} \hookrightarrow \Delta^{n}$, take $j \colon S \to T$ to be the inclusion $\emptyset \hookrightarrow \Delta^{0}$, $t \colon T \to X$ to be the 0-cell $x \colon \Delta^{0} \to C$, and $f \colon X \to Y$ to be unique map $C \xrightarrow{!} \Delta^{0}$.

Note that $$\left(\emptyset \hookrightarrow \Delta^{0}\right) \vartriangleright \left(C \xrightarrow{!} \Delta^{0}\right)$$ is precisely the map $\pi \colon C_{/x} \to C$ in your question.